# Pandas str.extract() a number that ends in a letter

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas column like below:

```
      df['description']
0.   PRAIRIE HIGHLANDS SIXTH PLAT Lt: 156 PIN# DP73770000 0156 312 ABC
1.   PRAIRIE VILLAGE   PIN# OP55000034 0020A Rmrk: PT OF
2.   Sub: HOLLY GREEN Lt: 14 Bl: 1 PIN# DP34500001 0D14
3.   FAIRWAY   PIN# GP20000006 0029 Rmrk: W
```

I want to extract out `PIN#` such that expected results:

```
DP73770000 0156 312
OP55000034 0020A
DP34500001 0D14
GP20000006 0029
```

What I have tried:

```
df['PIN'] = df['description'].str.extract(r'\b(?:PIN# ?) (\w+(?:(?:\s*[ ])+\s*\d+)*)\b')
```

Results I got:

```
DP73770000 0156 312
OP55000034
DP34500001
GP20000006 0029
```

The ones that have letters in between the numbers after space are not getting picked up. I have tried a couple other regex as well to no success. How can I resolve this? Please help.

Comment: Do the latter parts of the PIN# that you want always start with a digit? or is `PIN# XY12345678 D14` valid?

Comment: That would still be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `str.extract` as follows:

```py
df["PIN"] = df["description"].str.extract(r'PIN#((?: [A-Z0-9]*[0-9][A-Z0-9]*)*)')
```

Here is a link to a running regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ep2R8h/1) showing that the logic is working.